# Find minimum element in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-2.4

I need to find what element of `apple` has the minimum `size`.

Tnx for all answers. But there is one problem: I use Python 2.4.2 (I can't change it) and function `min` haven't `key` arg. Yes, I need key of `apple`

```
apple = {1:{'size':12,'color':'red'},2:{'size':10,'color':'green'}}
```

Comment: this kind of question has been asked a zillion times... min + key argument.

Comment: I would recommend you keep track of the min size as the dictionary of dictionaries is built.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python has a very nice parameter for the `min` function that allows using an arbitrary function to be minified instead of just using comparison on the elements:

```
result = min(apple.values(), key=lambda x:x['size'])
```

The `key` parameter replaced in most cases the older idiom of decorate-process-undecorate that could have been applied here:

```
result = min((x['size'], x) for x in apple.values())[1]
```

If instead you want to know the number (key) of the apple (it's not clear in the question) then:

```
result = min(apple.keys(), key=lambda x:apples[x]['size'])
```

or (old style)

```
result = min((apples[x]['size'], x) for x in apple.keys())[1]
```

Comment: This code fails to tell *which apple* (1 or 2) had the minimum value.

Comment: @senderle: you're right. I've been using javascript recently and that somewhat begins attacking my python reading ability.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: Indeed with my poor english I don't understand if what is requested is the key or the value from `apples`. I edited to consider both cases.

Comment: thanks, and +1 for explaining the "decorate-undecorate" idiom.

Answer (score 12):

```
import operator
min(apple.values(), key=operator.itemgetter('size'))
```

will return you

```
{'color': 'green', 'size': 10}
```

UPDATE: to get the index:

```
min(apple, key=lambda k: apple[k]['size'])
```

Comment: Still discovering the beauty of Python myself :).

Comment: Do you mean `apple.values()`?  Iterating through a dictionary gives you the keys.

Comment: Elegant code, but it doesn't tell you *which apple* has those attributes.

Comment: oops, it should have been apple.values.  I'll update the answer for that and @Steven's concern.

Answer (score 3):

Use `min` with a custom `key` function that returns the size of each item.

```
apple = {1:{'size':12,'color':'red'},2:{'size':10,'color':'green'}}
print min(apple.keys(), key=lambda k, a=apple: a[k]['size'])
```

Which prints:

```
2
```

P.S.  Since `apple` is a collection I would make it plural -- `apples`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's the fastest way to do it, but anyway:

```
>>> apple = [ {'size':12, 'color': 'red' }, { 'size':10, 'color':'green'} ]
>>> a = dict(map(lambda apple: (apple['size'], apple), apple))
>>> a
{10: {'color': 'green', 'size': 10}, 12: {'color': 'red', 'size': 12}}
>>> min = a[min(a.keys())]
>>> min
{'color': 'green', 'size': 10}
```

Comment: Your program gives the minimum value. Often we need the index of the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_min(apple):
    L = apple.values()
    m = L[0]
    for item in L:
        if item['size'] < m['size']:
            m = item
    return m
```

P.S. Not very pythonic but linear time

Answer (score 0):

```
min(map(lambda a:[apple[a]['size'],a], apple))[1]
```